# Delaying your action in combat

Tags: unknown-armies

I've read through the Unknown Armies combat rules, and can't see any RAW way that characters can choose to delay their action until later in the initiative order. Have I missed it, or is the option not there?

If it is not there, would a reasonable house rule be to allow it but that the position they delay to becomes their new initiative position for the rest of the fight?

Comment: Is there any reason it should have it? Not all RPGs do.

Comment: No, but given the importance of initiative order in a system where combat is so deadly, I consider it a valid tactical decision to make, and if its not in the rules I am interested in whether others have house-ruled it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A character may use their turn to change initiative. When you do so, you either set your initiative to your Initiative skill rating, or re-roll your initiative (this is the same process as the initial initiative roll/default at the start of combat).

There is no means to *specifically* lower your initiative, although a reroll could *potentially* do so, depending on your roll. That said, I can't think of any tactical reason why you would want the lower initiative value, as characters who are lower on the initiative are at a disadvantage (for example, when it comes to the dodge action).

Comment: The specific type of situation I was thinking of was waiting to see who a greater threat was, or who the shooter was targeting etc

Comment: @Phil, In UA, the tactical choice to gauge threats is to start dodging until you're ready to act on your observations. (And if, for example, your opponent has a weapon with a limited ammo supply before needing the reload, it's often intelligent to keep dodging until they run out.)